# Como utilizar a função `dplyr::rowwise` com mais de uma variável?

Tags: r

Considere o conjunto de dados abaixo:

```
df_1 <- data.frame(
  x = replicate(4, runif(30, 20, 100)), 
  y = sample(1:3, 30, replace = TRUE)
)
```

Fiz a seguinte análise:

```
library(tidyverse)

df_1 %>% 
  select(-y) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(var = sum(c(x.1, x.3)))
```

E a mesma dá certo. Mas, quero analisar todas as variáveis de uma só vez. Tentei isso de dois modos:

**1) Método convencional, utilizando o `.` como substituto das variáveis:**

```
df_1 %>% 
  select(-y) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(var = sum(.))
```

**2) Método `select_if`, para selecionar apenas as variáveis numéricas:**

```
df_1 %>% 
  select(-y) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(var = sum(select_if(., is.numeric)))
```

Os dois métodos acima retornam isso:

```
Source: local data frame [30 x 5]
Groups: <by row>

# A tibble: 30 x 5
     x.1   x.2   x.3   x.4   var
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  32.7  42.7  50.1  20.8 7091.
 2  75.9  71.3  83.6  77.6 7091.
 3  49.6  28.7  97.0  59.7 7091.
 4  47.4  96.1  31.9  79.7 7091.
 5  54.2  47.1  81.7  41.6 7091.
 6  27.9  58.1  97.4  25.9 7091.
 7  61.8  78.3  52.6  67.7 7091.
 8  85.4  51.3  38.8  82.0 7091.
 9  27.9  72.6  68.9  25.2 7091.
10  87.2  42.1  27.6  73.9 7091.
# ... with 20 more rows
```

Onde `7091.` é uma soma incorreta.

Como ajusto ambas funções? Também tentei um `mutate_at` no primeiro método, mas sem sucesso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No método 1 entendi que ele está retornando o valor total da soma de todos os objetos. No método 2 ocorre algo análogo.

```
set.seed(1)
df_1 <- data.frame(
  x = replicate(4, runif(30, 20, 100)), 
  y = sample(1:3, 30, replace = TRUE))

library(dplyr)
df_x <- df_1 %>% 
  dplyr::select(-y) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Var = rowSums(.))
```

---

```
> df_x
        x.1      x.2      x.3      x.4      Var
1  41.24069 58.56641 93.03007 39.17035 232.0075
2  49.76991 67.96527 43.48827 24.71475 185.9382
3  65.82827 59.48330 56.72526 71.38306 253.4199
4  92.65662 34.89741 46.59157 90.10154 264.2471
5  36.13455 86.18987 72.06964 82.31317 276.7072
. . .
```

---

- Utilizando o `for`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df_1 <- df_1 %>% 
  dplyr::select(-y)
df <- matrix(nrow = nrow(df_1), ncol = 1)
for (i in 1:nrow(df_1)) {
  valor <- df_1 %>% 
    dplyr::slice(i) %>% 
    dplyr::rowwise() %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(var = sum(.))
  df[i,1] <- valor$var

}
df <- as.data.frame(df)
df_1 <- df_1 %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(var = df[,1])
df_1
```

```
> df_1
        x.1      x.2      x.3      x.4      var
1  41.24069 58.56641 93.03007 39.17035 232.0075
2  49.76991 67.96527 43.48827 24.71475 185.9382
3  65.82827 59.48330 56.72526 71.38306 253.4199
4  92.65662 34.89741 46.59157 90.10154 264.2471

. . .
```

Comment: Olá, @bbiasi. Não consegue fornecer um exemplo usando `rowwise` ou qualquer outra função do `tidyverse` que faça a análise por linhas? Por exemplo, usando o `purrr::lift_vd`?

Comment: Atualizei a resposta, acrescentei um exemplo com `for`. Vou estudar essa função do `purrr` para ver a possibilidade, pois não conheço.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55922514/apply-dplyrrowwise-in-all-variables ?

Comment: Embora tenha feito esta pergunta, sempre gosto de explorar novas soluções com as mesmas funções (ou outras diferentes) para o mesmo problema. O exemplo com `for` é interessante. Obrigado.